# Django indentation error related to pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

I followed the tutorials to install django's pagination settings with python.  When I try to declare a paginator object in my views.py I receive an "Identation error" when I try to load the associated template.

I'm able to get pagination working without declaring a paginator in views.py, but I want to customize the page settings.

I imported the pagination directory at the top of my views.py, and I believe I set everything up in my settings.py folder.  I know I'm not misstyping the declaration because it's a simple one-liner:

> c = RequestContext(request, { "test": testObj, })
>
> p = Paginator (testObj, 100)
>
> return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

What could be causing this error?

Error:

```
IndentationError at /result/

unexpected indent (views.py, line 90)

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/result/xxx
Django Version:     1.5
Exception Type:     IndentationError
Exception Value:    

unexpected indent (views.py, line 90)

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\xxx',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_pagination-1.0.7-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Fri, 22 Mar 2013 14:38:29 -0400
```

Comment: Please post the exact error and the few lines of code immediately before and after `p = Paginator (test, 100)`.

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces in your source code? Run `tabnanny.py` on your script to see. Explanation of usage here: http://pymotw.com/2/tabnanny/index.html

Comment: "I know I'm not misstyping the declaration because it's a simple one-liner:" - I count three lines there? Not to mention, it's missing the `def` line?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what text editor you are using, but in gedit, you can display tabs and/or spaces as arrows, which can help to easily detect if there's stray tabs and/or spaces.

Comment: Sure: http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/

It's mainly used in Linux flavors but it seems to work fine for me in Windows.